# How can I modify messages on a queue, once sent

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I need to modify some of the messages that are already present in the queues.

Can it be possible to modify the message and send new modified message on the same queue for processing.
If yes, what would be the best approach for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. In JMS messages are immutable once they have been sent. If you find you need to modify messages its recommended that you create a consumer with some selector which matches the messages you wish to update, consume them and send new modified messages, either to another queue or if you are careful, back to the original queue.

ref link [Can I modify messages on a queue?](http://activemq.apache.org/can-i-modify-messages-on-a-queue.html)

my opinion is if you are consume the message using selector like correlationId,then consume the particular message from queue and again post the new message with same  correlationId of previous message.but this will depends up on your requirements.